# How do I set a Winforms DataGridView's rows header cell value when in virtual mode?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am trying edit the header cell value when using a grid view in virtual mode, but I can't get it working.

In my `CellValueNeeded` event I have the following code:

```
grvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = record.RecordNumber;
```

Unfortunately, my header cells are still displaying blank.

How can I get the row header values to display?  The end result is I need my rows to show what row number they are, to better keep track of data.

---

**Update:** The full event code is below:

```
    private void grvResults_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        const int BATCH_REQUEST_SIZE = 50;
        int row = e.RowIndex + 1;
        LogRecord record = null;

        // Check if this record for this row is cached
        if (!_recordCache.ContainsKey(row))
        {
            // Retrieve the requested record + a batch more to speed up operations and lessen queries
            int page = (row / BATCH_REQUEST_SIZE) + 1;

            var records = _currentStore.GetFilteredRecords(_filters, _currentSessionId, BATCH_REQUEST_SIZE, page);
            if (records.Count > 0)
            {
                // Add all the records to the cache
                for (int x = 0; x < records.Count; x++)
                    if (!_recordCache.ContainsKey(row + x))
                        _recordCache.Add(row + x, records[x]);
            }
        }

        // Get the record from the cache
        record = _recordCache[row];

        if (record != null)
        {
            // Set the header cell to the record number
            grvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = record.RecordNumber;

            // Match the cell to the field
            string cellFieldName = grvResults.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            if (record.Fields.Any(x => x.FieldName.Equals(cellFieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                e.Value = record.Fields.Where(x => x.FieldName.Equals(cellFieldName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Single().StringValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more code - I just tried setting the HeaderCell value when in virtual mode (from both inside CellValueNeeded and during other events) and it works fine.

Comment: I added the full CellValueNeeded method, but I don't see any other method that would affect this

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you sure RecordNumber is of type string? Integers will not be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the brief experiments I've done the HeaderCell.Value always shows in the row header, regardless of where it was set or whether the grid was in virtual mode.

One possibility is that the row header is too narrow to see the value.

Another is that RecordNumber is not a string - the Value displayed in the row header must be a string.

Comment: Doh, I didn't realize I couldn't just give it an int, I thought it would automatically `ToString()` it.  Changing it to `RecordNumber.ToString()` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me, I noticed I was applying the header to the new row and then overwriting it with a row with values but with no header, so just try this:

grvResults.Rows[e.RowIndex-1].HeaderCell.Value = record.RecordNumber;

(rowindex -1)